# How can I match an exact numeric string using in_array?

Tags: php, arrays

I use `in_array` to search a number in an array. When I searched `084` I got `true`. After that I searched for `84`, but I got `true` and "084" value.

How can I avoid that?

This is the code where the check is made:

```php
if (in_array(strval($_GET['search']), $vall))
{
    array_push($allwin,$number_array[0][0]);
}
```

The array I'm testing on is extracted from JSON that has values like these:

```
["\u0e40\u0e25\u0e02\u0e17\u0e49\u0e32\u0e223\u0e15\u0e31\u0e27","084","375"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because numerically, `084` and `84` both present the same number. Since by default `in_array` uses loose comparison, it will match them, as it will internally apply type conversion and both will be converted to `84`, as they are numeric.

If you look at the `in_array` [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), you will see it has a third parameter:

> `in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack , bool $strict = false ) : bool`

which determines whether loose or strict comparison should be used. Setting it to `true` would give you the desired result.

For example, if you were to run the following commands:

```php
var_dump(in_array(84, ['084', '756', '34']));
var_dump(in_array(84, ['084', '756', '34'], true));
var_dump(in_array('84', ['084', '756', '34'], true));
var_dump(in_array('084', ['084', '756', '34'], true));
```

they would output:

```
true // loose comparison, 84 == '084', both cast to numbers resulting in 84 being compared to 84
false // strict comparison, 84 !== '84', as one is int and the other string
false // strict comparison, '84' !== '084', as they're not identical strings, the second one has an extra character at the beginning
true // strict comparison, '084' === '084', identical strings
```